# Add column from table to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 2 tables:

- `Customers` table with `CustomerID` (PK) and `CustomerName` columns
- `Orders` table with `CustomerName` and `Product` columns

I want to add the `CustomerID` column to the `Orders` table so it fit to correct customer (which can appear more than one time on this table).

I tried by adding new column to the `Orders` table and then run this update :

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET NewColumn = (SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers 
                 WHERE CustomerName = Customers.CustomerName)
WHERE (NewColumn IS NULL)
```

The new column remained still `null`, however.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You want a `JOIN`, which is one if the first things you need to learn when using SQL; I suggest having a read up on them. Note, as well, a name is a bad choice for a Primary/Foreign key. Names are not unique (I've even met someone with the same name and date of birth as me), so do be prepared for errors when you write you query.

Comment: What’s the question? How to add a new column? Add the column, and update it joining by customername. Then, remove the customername column from product table

Comment: Also, the reason your question is getting voted down is likely due to lack of evidence of your attempts, or research. When posting a question, the **volunteers** you are asking for help from have certain expectations. One of those is making your question clear, and (if needed) reproducible. Another expectation is that you show your attempts and/or research into the subject. You haven't shown these. SO isn't a free coding service, and so questions that show a lack of due diligence attract down votes.

Comment: You should have 3 tables: CUSTOMER, PRODUCT, and ORDER.

Comment: Why CustomerName in second table if you have CustomerId in fist table you can add refrence of CustomerId to second table using Foreign key.

Comment: what kind of JOIN? inner/left/right/full ? btw, customerID is PK

Comment: Depends on your expected results @r.tom. Why I suggest you research the different types so you **you** understand them better. Us giving you an answer you don't understand is useless to you; you need to be able to understand and support any SQL you use.

Comment: i tried by addin new column to "Orders" and then : UPDATE Orders SET NewColumn = (select CustomerID from Customers where CustomerName = Customers.CustomerName) ; didn't work..

Comment: *"Didn't work."* doesn't tell us much. But you need to put information like that in your question, @r.tom not the comments. And be specific about how/why it didn't work.

Comment: by didn't work i mean the new column stay with all null's. ty, i will edit the main Q

Answer (score 1):

What you're after here is a `JOIN` like the below. Note, however, my comment I made under your answer. As a result this *might* not work, as names are not unique . (Comment under Question: *"Note, as well, a name is a bad choice for a Primary/Foreign key. Names are not unique (I've even met someone with the same name and date of birth as me), so do be prepared for errors when you write your query."*):

```
UPDATE O
SET NewColumn = C.CustomerID
FROM dbo.Orders O
     JOIN dbo.Customers ON O.CustomerName = C.CustomerName;
```

If you do end up with errors/anomalies, then we need to know how you determine which customer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the same column in both tables be explicit in where you are reading the column from.  The following should work:

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET NewColumn = (select Customers.CustomerID from Customers 
  where Orders.CustomerName = Customers.CustomerName)
WHERE NewColumn is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017